# How to implement a Wait screen in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am making a 2D Game in unity. It is split screen but the players are not in the same world, they are in copies of the same one. How can I make it so that the players have to wait for each other to finish the level before proceeding to the next. Also preferably have a "PLease Wait" message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I suggest creating a global controller for this. You can use something like "bool playerOneIsReady" (I don't know how many players you can have a the same time, a array or list will prove more flexible to the task).

Then, when a player reaches the end, you set his/her "isReady" controller to true, and display the message "Please wait" that you want.

Everytime someone is ready, check all the other ones to see if they all are ready too. If they are, proceed to the next world.

Good luck :)

Comment: Can I change the

void Awake()

to

void Awake(collision2d collision)

and do an if statement for when the player stands on a specific platform to start the wait screen?

Comment: You can't do it on Awake. Put a collider above the platform where the player can stand, make it a Trigger Collider on the inspector and use OnTriggerEnter2D